# rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am presently working on hyperledger. I have created a 4 organization network and I am trying create a channel from cli container. Below is the command

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f channel.tx
```

But i am getting an error as mentioned below:

```
2019-10-18 10:56:58.922 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
```

please help me solve this problem, Thanks in advance

Comment: Same here. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: The same while following this steps `https://medium.com/akeo-tech/step-by-step-guide-to-set-up-hyperledger-fabric-network-b80977c29b8a`